# ObjectDataSource could not find a non-generic method that takes parameters of type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, objectdatasource, detailsview

I've got a vexing problem with an ObjectDataSource (bound to a DetailsView) that is not checking the DeleteParameters for a delete method (which I specified both in the markup and the data object as requiring an integer). 
Here's the markup:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsFrontPageBannerDetails" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="FrontPage.Banner" DeleteMethod="DeleteFrontPageBanner" InsertMethod="InsertFrontPageBanner" SelectMethod="GetFrontPageBanner" UpdateMethod="UpdateFrontPageBanner" TypeName="FrontPage.BannersData">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="idx" Type="Int32"  />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="idx" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

and the object:

```
<DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete, True)> _
Public Shared Function DeleteFrontPageBanner(ByVal idx As Integer) As Integer
    Dim retval As Integer = 0
    Dim iReturnCode As Integer = 0
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(GetConnStr())
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "FrontPage_BannerDelete"
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idx", idx)
            Try
                conn.Open()
                iReturnCode = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                If iReturnCode >= 0 Then
                    retval = 1
                    LastErrorMsg = String.Empty
                Else
                    Throw New DataException("Return code is: " & iReturnCode)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                LastErrorMsg = ex.Message
                retval = 0
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    Return retval
End Function
```

and the detailsview markup:

```
   <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="odsFrontPageBannerDetails" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="338px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="idx" HeaderText="idx" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="idx" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BannerText" HeaderText="BannerText" SortExpression="BannerText" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BannerImage" HeaderText="Banner Image" SortExpression="BannerImage" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BannerLink" HeaderText="Go To Page Link" SortExpression="BannerLink" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BackgroundColor" HeaderText="Background Color" SortExpression="BackgroundColor" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BannerHeight" HeaderText="Banner Height" HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="BannerHeight" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HeaderText="Start Date" HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="StartDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HeaderText="End Date" HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="EndDate" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
        </Fields>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

The error indicates that the DeleteParameters are completely ignored! (I followed an example straight from a video tutorial and it worked fine for the author)

> ObjectDataSource 'odsFrontPageBannerDetails' could not find a
>   non-generic method 'DeleteFrontPageBanner' that takes parameters of
>   type 'FrontPage.Banner'.

Any ideas? I've tried rebuilding the solution and the page with no luck!

After trying every combination of parameters I could think of with no success, I decided to just change the delete method to accept the Frontpage.Banner object and now it deletes without an error - See change below:

```
<DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete, True)> _
Public Shared Function DeleteFrontPageBanner(ByVal o As FrontPage.Banner) As Integer
    Dim retval As Integer = 0
    Dim iReturnCode As Integer = 0
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(GetConnStr())
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "FrontPage_BannerDelete"
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idx", o.idx)
            Try
                conn.Open()
                iReturnCode = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                If iReturnCode >= 0 Then
                    retval = 1
                    LastErrorMsg = String.Empty
                Else
                    Throw New DataException("Return code is: " & iReturnCode)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                LastErrorMsg = ex.Message
                retval = 0
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    Return retval
End Function
```

Still would love an explanation of why the delete parameters in the markup are completely ignored.

Comment: Can you show the type definition whcih is holding your `DeleteFrontPageBanner` method?

Comment: <asp:Parameter Name="idx" Type="Int32"  />

Comment: I tried changing the target framework to 3.5 and recompiling (suggested in another forum), but that was no help. The code above, I did forget to add DataKeyNames="idx" on the detailsView.  Update and Insert work perfectly. It looks like a bug in the configuration utility, but I just need to know the proper manual configuration for the ObjectDataSource.   I'm going to try to just have the Delete method take in the whole object (instead of an integer) to see if that works.

Comment: Okay, It looks like you can only pass the same object to all the methods including the delete method w/ the ObjectDataSource. Go figure!

Comment: I don't think so, What I am asking you is does `DeleteFrontPageBanner` method reside in `FrontPage.BannersData` class?

Comment: Yes, as do the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Normally an object data source will resolve the method based upon the parameter names, in any order, and not checking the data types.

However if the DataObjectTypeName property is set, the method is resolved in a different way. The ObjectDataSource looks for a method with the name that is specified in the DeleteMethod property that takes one parameter of the type that is specified in the DataObjectTypeName property. In this case, the name of the parameter does not matter.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.deletemethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That's what I thought. What I don't understand is why examples showing the Delete methods have an integer parameter even though it should not work at all since you'd need to specify the same parameter that is used in the Update and Insert methods. Go figure.

Comment: Not sure what examples you have been using, perhaps you can provide a link, but it is certainly documented to work this way in the microsoft docs.